# Regex to replace TAB and move up lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

From below the verse i try to remove all the tab and join them using `<BR>`. But i want to untouch the lines that start with the verse number.

```
1       I am like one who gathers summer fruit
        at the gleaning of the vineyard;
        there is no cluster of grapes to eat,
        none of the early figs that I crave.

2       The faithful have been swept from the land;
        not one upright person remains.
        Everyone lies in wait to shed blood;
        they hunt each other with nets.

3       Both hands are skilled in doing evil;
        the ruler demands gifts,
        the judge accepts bribes,
        the powerful dictate what they desire—
        they all conspire together.
```

In Notepad++ find & replace, using regex i find `^\t` and replace with `<BR>` it replaces all the TAB. But i don't know how to join the lines so that it will become like this:

```
1       I am like one who gathers summer fruit<BR>at the gleaning of the vineyard;<BR>there is no cluster of grapes to eat,<BR>none of the early figs that I crave.
2       The faithful have been swept from the land;<BR>not one upright person remains.<BR>Everyone lies in wait to shed blood;<BR>they hunt each other with nets.
3       Both hands are skilled in doing evil;<BR>the ruler demands gifts,<BR>the judge accepts bribes,<BR>the powerful dictate what they desire—<BR>they all conspire together.
```

Can anyone please tell me how to join the lines using notepad++ regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should do it. Make sure to select "Regular Expression" under search mode.

```
 [\r\n]\s+(?![0-9])
```

Here's an explanation of the regex:

```
[\r\n] searches for newlines
\s+ multiple spaces
(?![0-9]) discard any results that are followed by numbers
```